# How to get the element of the new window and assign value in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, autohotkey

I use web_browser.document.getElementById() for the login screen it works fine, but when loggedin and opening a new window after login web_browser.document.getElementById does not seem to work please help. Please find the code below:

```
My_User_Name := "My_User_Name"

My_Pass_Word := "My_User_Name"

My_Batch := "C1-ADMOV"

web_browser := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")

web_browser.Visible := true

web_browser.Navigate("http://example.com")

while web_browser.busy ; a while loop is a way to keep the script testing an IF like expression

sleep 100 ; IF web_browser.busy is true then sleep 100 milliseconds


username_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("userId")

username_input.value := My_User_Name

password_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("password")

password_input.value := My_Pass_Word


web_browser.document.getElementById("loginButton").click()


while web_browser.busy ; a while loop is a way to keep the script testing an IF like expression

sleep 100 ; IF web_browser.busy is true then sleep 100 milliseconds


web_browser.Navigate2("http://example.com/batches")


while web_browser.busy ; a while loop is a way to keep the script testing an IF like expression

sleep 1000 ; IF web_browser.busy is true then sleep 1000 milliseconds


BATCH_CD_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("BATCH_CD")

BATCH_JOB_ID_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("BATCH_JOB_ID")

BATCH_CD_input.value := My_Batch

BATCH_JOB_ID_input.value:= "96090087688130"

web_browser.document.getElementById("lIM_Altr_bjSrch").click()

web_browser.document.getElementById("IM_Main_batjobSrch").click()

web_browser.document.getElementById("ACTION_Q_SW").click()


Return
```

Comment: Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

To access existing Internet Explorer windows that you didn't create using `ComObjCreate`, use something like this:

```
web_browser_from_active_window := IeGet()
web_browser_2 := IeGet("Login site bla bla")

IeGet(winTitle:="A") {
    WinGetTitle, title, % winTitle
    For window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").windows
        If (InStr(window.fullName, "iexplore.exe") && window.document.title . " - Internet Explorer" = title)
            Return window
    Return {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I managed to get elements I want on webpage. What I did instead of navigating to login page and enter credentials, I just navigate to the webpage I want to get elements in. I only have web_browser.Navigate2("http://example.com/batches"). This sorted my issue 


 My_User_Name := "My_User_Name"

My_Pass_Word := "My_User_Name"

My_Batch := "C1-ADMOV"

web_browser := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")

web_browser.Visible := true

web_browser.Navigate2("http://example.com/batches")

while web_browser.busy ; a while loop is a way to keep the script testing an IF like expression

sleep 100 ; IF web_browser.busy is true then sleep 100 milliseconds


username_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("userId")

username_input.value := My_User_Name

password_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("password")

password_input.value := My_Pass_Word


web_browser.document.getElementById("loginButton").click()


while web_browser.busy ; a while loop is a way to keep the script testing an IF like expression

sleep 100 ; IF web_browser.busy is true then sleep 100 milliseconds


while web_browser.busy ; a while loop is a way to keep the script testing an IF like expression

sleep 1000 ; IF web_browser.busy is true then sleep 1000 milliseconds


BATCH_CD_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("BATCH_CD")

BATCH_JOB_ID_input := web_browser.document.getElementById("BATCH_JOB_ID")

BATCH_CD_input.value := My_Batch

BATCH_JOB_ID_input.value:= "96090087688130"

web_browser.document.getElementById("lIM_Altr_bjSrch").click()

web_browser.document.getElementById("IM_Main_batjobSrch").click()

web_browser.document.getElementById("ACTION_Q_SW").click()


Return
```